# Java: Using a hash OR encryption/decryption to store level data

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm making a 2D java game, and I am working on the level saving/loading. I want to be able to save level data (right now it is just the positions of objects) in a way that people can't read it. I was thinking of either hashing the info using a key and a salt OR using encryption/decryption, if it was possible. What would the best way to do this be?  currently the positions are being stored as such:

```
165:240
256:145
248:337
245:244
359:235
73:111
72:367
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hashing and encryption aren't the same thing, and SHA-1 is hashing. You want encryption.

Comment: Oh whhops yea, I typed that out incorrectly. What would be the best encryption method OR hashing method to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can detect unauthorized edits with a hash. Compute an sha1 (or md5 of whatever) digest of the level data and save it when you save the level. When loading the level compute the hash again and if it doesn't match throw an error (or reset to level 1 or whatever). When you compute the hash include some secret data as salt - this can be hard coded.

You can prevent unauthorized edits with encryption. Generate a random number (or take the system tick or whatever) and use it to seed a random number generator which you then use as a one time pad to encrypt your level data when you save it (just xor each byte with the next random number). Don't forget to save your random number. When you load the data read your seed and use the same process to decrypt the level data. If someone edited the file it will decrypt to garbage.

Use both methods together by using the digest as your random seed.

Answer (score 1):

Not very serious: Most people can't read plain clear text, so...

More serious: aside from the fact that SHA-XXX is hashing (one way operation), it is really hard to encrypt something in a way that

- easily readable by local program
- not readable by a person who executes this local program on own local machine

You should figure out how much protection you want and use appropriate measures. Most likely simple compression of data (Zip) or even saving as bytes instead of clear text will be enough for most of the people. The rest will figure out what encryption is used to load saved game and will see what you have saved.

If you really want to protect saved data you need to save it away from user's machine. Even in this case it is still transmitted to/from user's machine and can be sniffed/modified.

Comment: The only thing I want to prevent is cheating e.g. going into the data and changing positions around, but even then it isn't that bad. I think I'm wanting to do this for more of a learning experience, if anything.

Comment: As gordy said - hashing (SHA, or MD5) is enough to detect changes made by casual user and for learning to use hashing/encryption. Just be aware that anything you can do on the user's machine can be repeated without your code by determined person.